# Postgres Crash: Investigation of "Background Worker 'Parallel Worker' (PID 8008) Termination with Exception 0xC0000022"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

We are encountering a problem with the Production setup, a crash when using PostgreSQL version 14.7. The following message is logged in the pg_log, leading to PostgreSQL entering recovery mode:

> "background worker ""parallel worker"" (PID 8008) was terminated by exception 0xC0000022",,"See C include file ""ntstatus.h"" for a description of the hexadecimal value.",,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0

- Database Type: POSTGRESQL 14.7
- OS Type: Windows Server 2012 R2

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

```
#define STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000022L)
```

Comment: So what did you find in *ntstatus.h*?

Comment: #define STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED    ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000022L)